# ajax.reload() NO funciona

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

estoy trabajando en un proyecto para el instituto pero no logro hacer que mediante ajax el DataTable se recargue despues de insertar el registro en la BD y en la consola se me genera este error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined
at Object.success (categoria.js:106) //esta es la linea en la cual llamo a ajax.reload()
at i (jquery3.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery3.min.js:2)
at A (jquery3.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery3.min.js:4)
```

el Codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
function list(){

$table= $("#tblistado").dataTable(
{
    "languaje": {
        "url":"cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json" 
//tampoco funciona el lenguaje 
//aunque de menor importancia para el proyecto

    },
    "aProcessing": true, //Activamos el procesamiento de datatables
    "aServerSide": true, //Paginacion y filtrados Realizados por el Servidor
    dom : 'Bfrtip', // Definimos los elementos del control de la tabla
    buttons:[
                'copy',
                'excel',
                'csv',
                'pdf'
            ],
    "ajax":         // se llama la Url AL CASE LISTAR POR METODO $_GET desde categoria.php
            {
                url: '../../ajax/categoria.php?operacion=list',
                type:"get",
                dataType:"json",
                error: function(e){ console.log(e.responseText);}

            },
    "bBdestroy": true,
    "iDisplayLenght": 5, //paginacion, es decir, cada cuanto elementos
    "order": [[0,"desc"]] //ordenar (columna, orden)

}).DataTable();
}
```

//Funcion para Guardar o editar

```
function saveAndEdit(e){

e.preventDefault();// No se activara la accion predeterminada del evento
$("#btnGuardar").prop("disabled",true);
var formData = new FormData($("#formulario")[0]);

jQuery.ajax({
        url:"../../ajax/categoria.php?operacion=saveandedit",
        type:"POST",
        data:formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

    success: function (datos){
        alert(datos);
        showForm(false);
        table.ajax.reload(); // linea 106 del error de la consola

    }
});

}
```

-me he asegurado de que sea Jquery el primero que se cargue ne el footer
-he intentado colocar $.ajax en lugar de jQuery.ajax
-he intentado usar table.api().ajax.reload()
-he intentado cambiar de dataTable a DataTable segun la documentacion 
Nada ha funcionado.

Adicional a esto pero de menor importancia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of **undefined**

table esta definido dentro de la función `list()`, por lo que no existe dentro de `saveAndEdit(e)`

Puedes acceder a ella:

```
success: function (datos){
    var table = $('#tblistado').DataTable(); // accede de nuevo a la DataTable.
    alert(datos);
    showForm(false);
    table.ajax.reload(); // linea 106 del error de la consola
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias has resuelto mi problema, por otro lado sabes por qué no se cambia el idioma del datatable ? tengo cargado el archivo de idioma como dice en la documentación , pero sigue apareciéndome en ingles, y tampoco parece funcionar la propidad // iDisplayLenght y sigue mostrandose todo por defecto , sin cambios. de antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda .

Comment: Abre una pregunta para que puedas mostrarme el código, y ver cómo lo estas usando.